# Programming through PBS

Tags: cluster-computing, grid-computing, pbs

I want to schedule a program on multiple nodes how can i do so.Im new to programming so I got some hint about PBS.How can I do it with the following.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have a particular problem, you should describe it in your question. If you have no idea how to deal with PBS, you should read the following:

http://www.phy.bme.hu/~cluster/docs/PBS.html
http://www.adaptivecomputing.com/resources/docs/torque/index.php (section 2)

Once again, I advise you to post a complete description of what you want to submit on your cluster (kind of job, input data, output data, number of jobs, ...), so that we can help you a bit more.